# Insert text next to selected cell - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an "If/Then" code snippet which changes the integer in a cell if the condition is true. What I would like to do is insert text next to that cell to indicate it has been manipulated.

Eg:

```
Public Sub testforfifty()
    Dim rcell As Range, rng As Range
    Set rng = Application.ActiveSheet.Range("D1:D" & Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count)
    For Each rcell In rng.Cells
        If rcell.Value > 50 And rcell.Value < 100 Then rcell.Value = rcell.Value - 50
        If rcell.Value >= 100 Then rcell.Value = "NoSplit"
    Next rcell
End Sub
```

If the cell is `>=100` then the cell's Value is just changed to `"No Split"` which is fine, but if the number is say `55`, then the cell becomes the number `5`. I want the cell next to it to say `Manipulated` now so the user can differentiate that the cell has been manipulated by the macro.

Can somebody point me in the correct direction? Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split out your if statement from:

```
If rcell.Value > 50 And rcell.Value < 100 Then rcell.Value = rcell.Value - 50
```

To:

```
If rcell.Value > 50 And rcell.Value < 100 Then 
    rcell.Value = rcell.Value - 50
    rcell.offset(0,1).value = "Manipulated"
End if
```